# #selector para función local, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Tengo una condición if donde dentro de ella declaro `var capturedImage = UIImage(data: dataImage)`. Necesito acceder a ella mediante una función llamada `addImage()` y luego llamar a esta función con un botón llamado `okButton` de la siguiente manera:

```
okButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addImage(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

El problema es que tengo que declarar la función `addImage()` y el `addTarget` del botón dentro de la misma condición if pero me sale un error donde me dice que #selector no puede referirse a una función local. Este es mi código.

```
if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

  var capturedImage = UIImage(data: dataImage)

  func addImage(sender: UIButton) {

     let data: NSData = capturedImage

     print("capturedImage is now NSData")

  }

  /*Aqui aparece el error --->*/ okButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addImage(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}
```

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con este código no sé de donde vienen ni photoSampleBuffer ni previewPhotoSampleBuffer, suponiendo que en ViewWillAppear, puedas recoger esas variables, yo cambiaría un poco el código:

Para empezar si vas a mostrar/ocultar el botón, añádele el target una única vez, en `viewDidLoad`. Así el botón tendrá establecido su target desde el principio pero sólo será accesible cuando lo muestres `self.okButton.isHidden = false`

Por lo demás, no reutilices la variable `capturedImage`, crea variables temporales, y cuando realmente obtengas la imagen deseada, ya se la asignas a `capturedImage`, de lo contrario, alguno de los productos intermedios podría quedar asignado a tu variable, y ser mostrado en su lugar.

Para hacer un print, no necesitas hacer `DispatchQueue.main.async` ya que no estás haciendo nada en el UI.

Por último, tal y como te dije en mi respuesta anterior, necesitas sacar la función del scope de viewWillAppear, o de lo contrario no te funcionará.

```
var capturedImage: UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    okButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addImage(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer, let dataImage =   AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {

        let cameraPosition = currentVideoInput?.device.position

        if let image = UIImage(data: dataImage), cameraPosition == .front {

            capturedImage = UIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored)

            self.tempImageView.image = capturedImage
            self.tempImageView.isHidden = false
            self.okButton.isHidden = false
            self.cameraView.isHidden = true
            self.yellowButton.isHidden = true
            self.toggleAction.isHidden = true
            self.adorButton.isHidden = true
            self.flashButton.isHidden = true                
        }
       print(self.capturedImage!)
    }
}

func addImage(sender: UIButton) {
    if let image = capturedImage {
        if let data: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
             print("capturedImage is now Data")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: se esta ejecutando en viewWillAppear

Comment: Te paso mi código para que veas como lo añadí y ver si todo esta bien @jdev: https://gist.github.com/sebasvarelagmz/607dee7505b031a2045574f3d17cf271

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, modificándola para utilizarla en viewWillAppear

Comment: Muchas gracias @jdev, el código funciona a la perfección. 